Mobile Application : Migration from Xamarin to net8.0. Android library is not recognized
I have to migrate a Xamarin/C# application to net8.0 because of Xamarin end of support.
I am not a specialist of C#, .NET technologies, and I have just made a few modifications in this application and I have no colleagues to help me.
In Visual Studio 17.9.6, this application has an architecture like this :

MVision.Android
MVision.iOS
MVision.Library. MVision Library is needed to compile MVision.Android, and MVision.iOS.

What I have done from the moment :

Replace MonoAndroidv13.0 framework by net8.0 framework. (I have not use Maui framework because it is not a Xamarin forms application. Is is correct ?)
Regenerate .csproj files.
Replace all Xamarin.Android libraries by Xamarin.AndroidX libraries.
Correct all Errors I can. (More than 800 !)

Some errors are still here like for Example :
I have code :
using Android.Content ==> this like works because Android.Content is recognized in net8.0 (as it was in MonoAndroidv13.0)
var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);

==> This line does not work because
Erreur  CS0234  Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'Content' n'existe pas dans l'espace de noms 'MVision.Android' (vous manque-t-il une référence d'assembly ?).
I think this is a confusion between Android (from framework .net8.0) and MVision.Android (name of my project).
How to solve this ?
Best regards.
Christophe.

use a namespace alias or global namespace
